# YAML data exchange issues between Perl and Ruby

Tags: ruby, perl, yaml

I'm having trouble with data being exchanged between Perl and Ruby via YAML. I have some values that look like number:number, such as `1:16`.

Perl's YAML libraries (Tiny and XS) encode this as `1:16` without quotes. Ruby's YAML library (Psych) does not interpret this as a string, but instead somehow becomes the Fixnum value `4560`. I can't figure out how to fix this conversion issue on either side.

Every value in the YAML for my use case should be an object or string.  So, I could tell the Perl YAML library to quote all values, if such an option existed. Or is there any way to tell the Ruby YAML library to interpret all values as strings? Any ideas?

Changing the language on either side is not logistically an option.

Perl:

```
use YAML::XS qw(DumpFile);
my $foo={'abc'=>'1:16'};
DumpFile('test.yaml',$foo);
```

Ruby:

```
require('yaml')
foo=YAML.load_file('test.yaml')
puts(foo['abc'])
```

The Ruby code will print `4560`. One of the comments figured out how you get `4560` from `1:16`, it's 1 hour, 16 minutes converted to seconds.  Uh, okay.

Comment: Could you give some sample YAML data along with Ruby and Perl code you're using for decoding?

Comment: 4560 is the number of seconds in one hour and 16 minutes (assuming no leap seconds).

Comment: What does the generated YAML file look like?

Comment: @bta, As it it was produced by `"---\nabc: 1:16\n"`

Comment: As best as I can tell, the problem is on the Ruby side. Is there another parser you can use?

Comment: Looked at a few parsers on the Perl side, and I see no options along the line of "always quote".

Comment: I read that Ruby has bindings for `libsyck`. Maybe that module would work? Perl bindings to `libsyck` work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Yaml 1.1 spec](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id858600), `1:16` is an integer in sexagesimal (base 60) format.

See also http://yaml.org/type/int.html, which says:

> Using “:” allows expressing integers in base 60, which is convenient for time and angle values.

The Yaml parser included in Ruby, Psych, [recognises this format and converts the value into an integer](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/v1.3.2/lib/psych/scalar_scanner.rb#L68-73) (wrongly, `1:16` shoud be 71 – the Psych code seems to asume that all such values will be in the form `a:b:c` but the regex doesn’t enforce that). The Perl  emitter (at least YAML::XS which I tested) doesn’t recognise this format, so doesn’t quote the string when writing the file. YAML::XS *does* recognise and quote some integers, but not all. YAML::XS also doesn’t recognise many other formats (e.g. dates) that Psych does.

(It appears that the sexagesimal format [has been removed from the Yaml 1.2 spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2761292).)

Psych allows quite a deal of flexibility in its parsing – `YAML.load_file` is just a simple interface for the common use cases.

You could use the `parse` methods of Psych to create a tree representation of the yaml, then convert this into a Ruby data structure using a custom `ScalarScanner` (which is the object that converts strings of certain formats to the appropriate Ruby type):

```ruby
require('yaml')

class MyScalarScanner < Psych::ScalarScanner
  def tokenize string
    #this is the same regexp as Psych uses to detect base 60 ints:
    return string if string =~ /^[-+]?[0-9][0-9_]*(:[0-5]?[0-9])+$/
    super
  end
end

tree = YAML::parse_file 'test.yaml'
foo = Psych::Visitors::ToRuby.new(MyScalarScanner.new).accept tree
```

This is basically the same process that occurs when you use `YAML.load_file`, except that it uses the customised scanner class.

A similar alternative would be to open up `ScalarScanner` and replace the `tokenize` method with the customised one. This would allow you to use the simpler `load_file` interface, but with the usual caveats about monkey patching classes:

```ruby
class Psych::ScalarScanner
  alias :orig_tokenize :tokenize
  def tokenize string
    return string if string =~ /^[-+]?[0-9][0-9_]*(:[0-5]?[0-9])+$/
    orig_tokenize string
  end
end

foo = YAML.load_file 'test.yaml'
```

Note that these examples only take into consideration values with a format like `1:16`. Depending on what your Perl program is emitting you may need to override other patterns too.  One in particular that you might want to look at is sexagesimal floats (e.g. `1:16.44`).

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in the parser you are using. It seems to think `1:16` is some kind of time (since 4560 is the number of seconds in one hour and 16 minutes), but I find nothing that validates that interpretation.

The best solution would be to use a parser that isn't buggy.

- `libyaml`, used by YAML::XS, supposedly has Ruby bindings.
- `libsyck`, used by YAML::Syck, supposedly has Ruby bindings.

An alternative is to generate YAML where the strings are always quoted (or at least when they would be treated as as time).

[YAML::Syck](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAML%3a%3aSyck) has an option to do exactly that.

```
$ perl -e'
   use YAML::Syck qw( Dump );
   local $YAML::Syck::SingleQuote = 1;
   print(Dump({abc=>"1:16"}));
'
--- 
"abc": '1:16'
```

(Don't know how I missed this option earlier!)

Comment: I have tried YAML::XS.  It has the same issue.  The YAML::Syck makes me very nervous.  Here is quote from CPAN page for YAML::Syck -

"This module has a lot of known issues and has only been semi-actively maintained since 2007. If you encounter an issue with it probably won't be fixed unless you offer up a patch in Git that's ready for release."

The Ruby documentation says basically the same thing.

Comment: I didn't say you should use YAML::XS -- Actually you already are according to what you said -- I said you should try using libyaml or libsyck \in Ruby.

Answer (score -4):

Ruby interprets all YAML entries as strings, unless they fit [a handful of special formats](http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#basic_types).  The entry `1:16` looks like it matches the special format for a time, so Ruby is mis-interpreting it.

You need to force Ruby to interpret the field as a string.  There are two ways to do this.  Either of the following YAML outputs should give you the result that you want:

```
abc: !str 1:16
abc: '1:16'
```

To generate this output, try the following Perl code:

```
my $foo={'abc'=>'!str 1:16'};
my $foo={'abc'=>"'1:16'"};
```

**Update:**
I was able to pass data between Perl and Ruby using the following code:

Perl:

```
use YAML::XS qw(DumpFile);
my $foo={'abc'=>'1:16'};
DumpFile('test.yaml',$foo);
```

Ruby:

```
require 'yaml'
foo=YAML.parse_file('test.yaml')
foo['abc'].value
=> "1:16"
foo['abc'].value.class
=> String
```

The result is a bit more complicated to use than the simple hash that `load_file` returns, but it looks like it's at least parsing the file as expected.

Comment: That correctly produces `abc: '!str 1:16'` and `abc: '''1:16'''` respectively. I believe neither will produce the correct result in Ruby.

Comment: `1:16` doesn't match any of the formats listed in the document you linked.

Comment: @ikegami- It matches the format for a simple time, although the limited examples on that page use more complex samples.  Ruby has many possible output format options for date and time objects, and it appears that the YAML parser is flagging anything that might even possibly be a date.  My Perl skills are extremely rusty, so you may have to tweak it to get YAML output in the format I listed.

Comment: I can't use this method, because the YAML has to be consumed by other Perl programs as well, and they don't seem to understand the !str operator.

Comment: @DouglasMauch- If perl isn't understanding the '!str' operator, does it parse a quoted argument correctly?  If so, the second form may still be useful to you.  Also, please check and ensure that the Ruby and Perl modules are conforming to the same version of the YAML spec.  Using different spec versions can lead to all sorts of interoperability problems.

Comment: @DouglasMauch- The problem may have something to do with the method that your Ruby code is using.  See my updated answer for an example that worked on my system.